# Hash symbol in URL via GET

Tags: php, get, urlencode

I am trying to pass a text string with the symbol `#` in it and I am having problems receiving the GET method with PHP.

I tried to change the symbol `#` by `%23` directly in the URL and it does not work.

I have a file type `/tests.php?value=hello#world` and I need to make that symbol `#` be treated as plain text and not as a special HTML anchor character.

Any ideas?

Comment: `value=hello%23world` Should work: `<?php var_dump($_GET['value']); ?>` yields: `string(11) "hello#world"`

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you mean by "having problems" and "does not work"? What indicates the problem? What happens that isn't supposed to happen or vice versa?

Comment: I have managed to work with a URL of the type `/tests.php?filter=all&value=hello%23world`, but when applied to a friendly URL the variable `$_GET['value']` only shows me `hello`.

Comment: I'm sorry, and I managed to make it work, I needed to put `[B]` at the end of the rule for the friendly URL in the `.htaccess`.